# MySQL, index was out of range.Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: mysql, sql, workbench

[image]

whenever I am trying to find data from MySQL workbench, Index problem is popping up!! I have no idea to fix this problem.

would help me to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Please share more details - is this even related to programming?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in Workbench: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86090 [1]
Duplicate: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=81625 [2]
[2] has a comment at the end, from 26 May 2020 saying that the bug persists in 8.0.16, although in [1] it says 8.0.14 has this issue fixed.
As of writing this comment, the latest version is 8.0.24.